# Access word value inside object

Tags: object, scope, rebol, rebol3, red

In the interpreter:

```
>>  qurl: "1234"
== "1234"

>> R: make object! [probe qurl qq: qurl probe qq]
"1234"
"1234"
== make object! [
    qq: "1234"
]
```

This behaves like I'd expect.  All "variables" or "words" are global by default.

Using a script:

```
REBOL []

qurl: "1234"

Q: make object! [
    probe join "[Q before qq] qurl: " qurl
    qq: qurl
    probe join "[Q] qq: " qq
    qurl: qurl
    probe join "[Q after qurl] qurl: " qurl
]
probe join "[main before Q] qurl: " qurl
Q
probe join "[main after Q] qurl: " qurl
```

returns:

```
"[Q before qq] qurl: none"
"[Q] qq: none"
"[Q after qurl] qurl: none"
"[main before Q] qurl: 1234"
"[main after Q] qurl: 1234"
```

I'd expect that all `probe` inside the `Q` `object!` would return `"1234"`, but none does it.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Rebol creates an object, it collects the (set-)words from the spec first and uses them to create the new object. The words of the new object are initially assigned to `none`. The spec is then bound to the new object and evaluated.

In your first example, you haven't included `qurl:` in your spec, thus is not part of your object. Instead you get the 'global' `qurl`. In your second example, `qurl` *is* part of your object and is initiated with `none`.

Your options to access the value associated with the 'global' `qurl` in your second example are:

1. Compose the block so that when the block is evaluated, it accesses the value directly:

```
Q: make object! compose [
    qq: (qurl)
    qurl: (qurl)
]
```

2. Access the word from a 'global' context:

```
Q: make object! [
    qq: system/words/qurl ; Rebol 2
    qq: system/contexts/user/qurl ; Rebol 3
]
```

Comment: In the example 1., the parenthesis are a kind of evaluation?

Comment: @luis Yes—`compose` is an indispensable function that allows you to preprocess a block in a controlled way. It's similar to `reduce` except that only paren! values within a block are reduced.